# Flying saucer word wraps before punctuation in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, flying-saucer

I started using Flying Saucer to convert XHTML to PDF, and I'm seeing that word wrap is handled incorrectly.

In browser:

```
How do you   |
do?          |
Purple,      |
green, blue. |
```

In PDF:

```
How do you do|
?            |
Purple, green|
, blue.      |
```

Looks like Flying Saucer is not treating punctuation as part of the word when word wrapping.

I tried `doc.normalize()` as suggested [here](http://abhirampal.com/2012/04/18/pdf-document-word-split-using-flying-saucerxhtml-renderer/), but that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

w3c.dom.Document.normalizeDocument() – is that the method you used?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#normalizeDocument()

Comment: I tried org.w3c.dom.Node.normalize() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#normalize()

Comment: Ok- Document.normalizeDocument worked for me when I had the problem. Node.normalize() should work for you since Node.normalize() seems to do the same thing as normlizeDocument. Only thing I can suggest is check your DOMConfiguration https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getDomConfig() and play around with the attributes as the bheviour of the normalize method depends upon DOMConfiguration.